# How can i make random generated quotes

Tags: coronasdk

Hi i am beginner in corona how would i randomly generate quote on screen

example:

"first quote"
 "second quote"
 "third qoute"

and when user taps it shows only one randomly generated quote from those three

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "quote"?

Comment: Do you mean like [fortune](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune_%28Unix%29)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
  --Create your quote array with quote strings
  local myQuoteArray = {"first quote",
                      "second quote",
                      "third quote"}

  --Display a label and postion it on the screen --
  local myLabel = display.newText("Initial string",0,0,nil,14)
  myLabel.x = display.contentWidth/2
  myLabel.y = display.contentHeight/2
  myLabel:setTextColor(255)

  --Function for restting the label with any random string from 'myQuoteArray' 
  local function setLabelString()
    --Take any string from the array within its range/count (#myQuoteArray)
    --And reset the label/text with the new string/quote
    myLabel.text = myQuoteArray[math.random(#myQuoteArray)]
  end
Runtime:addEventListener("tap",setLabelString)
```

Keep Coding.................... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can define an table with these three quotes:

```
local quotes= {}
quotes[1] = "first quote"
quotes[2] = "second quote"
quotes[1] = "third quote"
```

Create the label

```
local label=display.newText{
    text="",
    x=0,y=100,
    width=100,height=40,
    font=native.systemFrom,
    fontSize=16
 }
```

Init the random number generator

```
math.randomseed( os.time() )
```

Then create a button:

```
local handleRelease = function(event)
  local index=math.random(3)
  local quote=quotes[index]
  label.text = quote
end


local button = widget.newButton{
   x=0, y=0,
   width=100, height=40,
   label="Press me",
   onRelease = handleRelease
}
```

You need to call this from within a scene to get them displayed.